# Using Xrm.WebApi method in Web Resource opened in a new window

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have opened an HTML web resource in a new window using:

`Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource(webResource, windowOptions, data);`

This is an HTML web resource and it is loading the ClientObject in the head

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" ></script>`

then I have some JavaScript that is trying to retrieve a `Contact`

```
var contactId = "8553DA63-11C9-E711-A824-000D3AE0CB84";
var promise = Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contact", contactId, "$select=contactid,firstname,lastname");`
```

but this is **failing**. I've step-traced into the `Xrm.WebApi` method and found the error is when it attempts to resolve `"contact"` to a `Set Name`

> Code from **Global.ashx**
>
> ```
> getEntitySetName: function(logicalName) {
>     Mscrm.Utilities.addTelemetryLog("Xrm.Utility.getEntitySetName");
>     var $v_0 = window.ENTITY_SET_NAMES || window.top.ENTITY_SET_NAMES;
>     if (IsNull(this.$5H_1) && !isNullOrEmptyString($v_0))
>         this.$5H_1 = JSON.parse($v_0);
>     return this.$5H_1[logicalName.toLowerCase()]
> },
> ```

For some reason the `window.ENTITY_SET_NAMES` object is null so an error (null reference) occurs

I've tried embedding my web resource into a CRM page and the code works correctly. The issue seems to be when the web resource is launched via  `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource`

Has anyone tried to use `Xrm.WebApi` in the context of an web resource opened with `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource`? or does anyone know if there are additional steps required to retrieve data?

---

**Update**

`ENTITY_SET_NAMES` is initialised in `main.aspx`.
I tried embedding my custom Web Resource directly into a new `Main Form` section and the `retrieveRecord` method works.

It appears this is a problem only when running the Web Resource from a new page via `Xrm.Navigation.openWebResource`

---

**Update 2 - Response to Aron**

I tried using `window.parent` as suggested below

```
var contactId = "8553DA63-11C9-E711-A824-000D3AE0CB84";
var promise = parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contact", contactId, "$select=contactid,firstname,lastname");`
```

and for good measure also tried `window.parent.top`

```
var contactId = "8553DA63-11C9-E711-A824-000D3AE0CB84";
var promise = parent.top.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contact", contactId, "$select=contactid,firstname,lastname");`
```

but both resulted in the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [blog](https://jasonscript.wordpress.com/2018/07/25/using-xrm-webapi-in-popup-window/) :)

---

To get this working I have implemented a *hacky* work-around.

I've been debugging the Xrm.WebApi method and it is failing on a line where it attempts to take the **entityname** and resolve it to the **setname** (plural). It does this by comparing the value passed into the `retrieveRecord` method and comparing it to a global variable `ENTITY_SET_NAMES`

> In my example, it is trying to resolve `contact` to `contacts`

This variable is unfortunately not present and `Xrm.WebApi` throws an error

My work-around is to check for this variable, and if it is **not** present then create it! `ENTITY_SET_NAMES` is a JSON-parsable string which contains the logical name and set name for each entity.

```
window["ENTITY_SET_NAMES"] = window["ENTITY_SET_NAMES"] || JSON.stringify({
  "account" : "accounts",
  "contact" : "contacts"
});
```

Executing this line before any calls to `Xrm.WebApi` methods appears to work and I now get results

Here's the complete snippet:

```
window["ENTITY_SET_NAMES"] = window["ENTITY_SET_NAMES"] || JSON.stringify({
  "account" : "accounts",
  "contact" : "contacts"
});

var contactId = "8553DA63-11C9-E711-A824-000D3AE0CB84";
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord(
  "contact", 
  contactId, 
  "$select=contactid,firstname,lastname"
).then(
  function success(result) {
    console.log(result.firstname);
    // perform operations on record retrieval
  },
  function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    // handle error conditions
  }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a product bug within `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx`, as this should give you whole context to work with.

Probably you can utilize `window.opener.Xrm` in this scenario, since [it worked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51485579/7920473) for `window.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute` it should also work for `Xrm.WebApi`.

You can try to access variable from opener window like this:

```
window["ENTITY_SET_NAMES"] = window["ENTITY_SET_NAMES"] || window.opener.top.ENTITY_SET_NAMES;
```

Comment: I have to specify **top** but it works: `window.opener.top.ENTITY_SET_NAMES`

Answer (score 2):

As per [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg309536.aspx), when referencing the main form from a Web Resource we have to reference the parent window. Though, it only references Xrm.Page and Xrm.Utility, it should also work with Xrm.WebApi...

> An HTML web resource added to a form can’t use global objects defined by the JavaScript library loaded in the form. An HTML web resource may interact with the **Xrm.Page** or **Xrm.Utility** objects within the form by using **parent.Xrm.Page** or **parent.Xrm.Utility**, but global objects defined by form scripts won’t be accessible using the parent.

Please try  `parent.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contact", contactId, "$select=contactid,firstname,lastname");`

[This article](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=2852) also demonstrates `parent.Xrm.WebApi`

Comment: great find Aron. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I've updated my question with my test results

Comment: Thanks for the update. Since the code works when embedded in the form but fails when opened in a new window, it seems that opening the new window creates a new `window` object, which breaks `window.ENTITY_SET_NAMES`. Perhaps you can retrieve it from the parent window and set it on the child window to enable Xrm.WebApi. Or, when working in a new window, perhaps "roll your own" Web API calls. For that purpose [Jason Lattimer's CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) is very handy.

Comment: I couldn't retrieve it from the parent window - it was null. The solution I eventually settled on was to create my own ENTITY_SET_NAME global variable with only the values I need. I've added my own answer if you want to see more detail

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use bound actions & functions you'll also need to add a similar variable to map entities to their primary id fields.

```js
window["ENTITY_PRIMARY_KEYS"] = ['{"account":"accountid", "contact":"contactid"}'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using opener.Xrm to access the Xrm object in a standalone webresource opened from a form as described here in the parent.Xrm section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming#some-client-apis-are-deprecated

"If the getContentWindow method doesn't work, you can use parent.Xrm to get to the Xrm object inside an HTML web resource. If the HTML web resource is opened in a new window, then you should use opener.Xrm instead."

```
var contactId = "8553DA63-11C9-E711-A824-000D3AE0CB84";
var promise = opener.Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("contact", contactId, "$select=contactid,firstname,lastname");
```