# Xrm object undefined on SiteMap Html web resource in D365 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I have an Angular html page that has script reference to the javascript. In the Javascript I am using `Xrm` object to make certain actions like `Xrm.webApi.retrieveMultipleRecords` etc..

This Angular Html Web resource is loaded as part of SiteMap. The Angular Html web resource also have script reference to "ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" and able to access `Xrm` object.

If I remove the aspx script reference the `Xrm` object is undefined. Microsoft docs mention that this script reference doesn't make the `Xrm` object available but in my case it's exactly what it is doing.

Then I tried removing the "ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" reference and started using `parent.Xrm` object and everything seems to be working fine again. But the Microsoft docs again said that parent.Xrm will not work if loading an HTML web resource as part of SiteMap which exactly is my scenario and seems to be working.

So need to know what I should do as I don't want to use any methods that's going to be deprecated.

Here is the link to the Microsoft docs: [Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS7o8.png) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/getglobalcontext-clientglobalcontext.js.aspx

Comment: Are you attempting to access the form via the Xrm. Syntax, or the Global Context, Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext(), or both?

Comment: It is not the form. I am trying to access the Xrm object within a Html Web Resource that loaded by the SiteMap. Without use of the "ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" script reference, the Xrm object is undefined (which contradicts to the screenshot). If i use parent.Xrm then i am able to make the webApi calls but again this contradicts to the screenshot hightlighted part as well. So want to know what's the right approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using `Xrm.WebApi` object in a Web Resource as well.

See here: [Using Xrm.WebApi method in Web Resource opened in a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416490/using-xrm-webapi-method-in-web-resource-opened-in-a-new-window)

The short answer is, is that the methods rely on JavaScript constants that are only loaded on the CRM pages. You can work-around the issue by providing your own constants, and copy the values from `window.opener.top`.